# Protocol spec for FTP through HTTP

Tags: http, networking, proxy, ftp

It is possible to do a ftp request through HTTP proxy. You could connect to a HTTP proxy and send a request like this:

GET ftp://ftp.example.com/example.txt HTTP/1.1

I guess it is possible to do upload too though HTTP proxy. I want to parse these (FTP over HTTP) requests that a browser could make. I Googled to see if I could find the protocol spec for these requests. I couldn't find any. Could someone point out to the protocol used for doing ftp upload/download using HTTP proxy?

Note that I'm not talking about tunneling using the HTTP CONNECT. I'm guessing the protocol is just like that of HTTP expect for using "ftp://" instead of "http://". But I would like to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. In this case client -> proxy connection is HTTP and the connection from Proxy to the Destination Server is FTP.

There is not specific Protocol specification because HTTP and FTP are used as is.

The proxy will convert the HTTP requests on the client connection into proper FTP commands. This will include authentication, down and uploads depending on the proxy implementation.

The vendors of commercial secure web proxies offer some help pages, google `ftp over http authentication`

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure upload will not work at all.  Even though you are using an FTP URI, if you examine the request and response between the client and proxy you will see it is actually HTTP.